# Check if list contains an element and append to another list's values to a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append

I have 3 lists :

```
A = [32, 33, 54, 66, 67]
B = [33, 4, 67]
C = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

What i'm trying to do is that i want to check if for every element in list A is in B, then it should append an element from C by order to a list D, if not, then it should append an empty string, and here is the result i'm looking for :

```
D = ['', 'A', '', '', 'B']
```

and here is what i wrote, but i get back a nested list C of all elements inside it in every position where A is in B, so i should also loop for every element in C, can you please tell me how i can do that ?

```
D = []

for a in A:
    if a in B:
        D.append(C)
    else:
        D.append('')


result: D = ['', [A, B, C], '', '', [A, B, C]]
```

thank you so much

Comment: But as per you description the expected output should be `['', 'A', '', '', 'C']`

Comment: This is a very confusing description. First of all, if `A`, `B`, and  `C`, are _variables_, then `C = [A, B, C]` would not work. Second, what happens if list `C` is short(er than the number of matches)? _"... append an element from C by order..."_ describe this in more detail.

Comment: Do lists `B` and `C` have an equal number of elements? Is that guaranteed?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny No, the result is : D = ['', [A, B, C], '', '', [A, B, C]]

Comment: @AGNGazer, i know C isn't gonna work in this case, let's assume its C = ['A', 'B', 'C'], and please note that the strings 'A', 'B', 'C' have nothing to do with the variables A and B, and for your second question, if C is shorter, and for example we only have 2 matches, then it should append the 'A' and 'B' only if we only have 1 match it should append 'A', for 3rd question, that's what i meant when i said it should append 'A' first, then 'B' then 'C' according to matches, and another info, B and C variables will have same number of elements, guaranteed.

Comment: What about the case when `A` and `B` have 10 elements with 5 of them matching and list `C` having only 3 elements? What should be appended for matches `#4` and `#5`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this code first:

Explain: you want to advance the item in list ***C*** if the required condition met.  Using the ***iter*** is like a pointer to loop and *next* will go to next item.

```py
expected = ['', 'A', '', '', 'B']

it = iter(C)                     # it's looping C as a pointer

D = []
for x in A:
    if x in set(B):
        D.append(next(it))
    else:
        D.append('')

        
print(D)
# ['', 'A', '', '', 'B'] == expected *result*
```